# How do I compare a user passed y/m/d string to date time in mysql?

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I have a variable that a user specifies `$start_date` in format of `y-m-d`.

so let's say for example `$start_date = '2011-10-27';`

In my database I have a DATETIME field, let's call it sample_date that looks like this
`2011-10-27 14:15:20`

When I run sql query using $start_date.. do I have to convert to compare the dates such as

```
SELECT * from content WHERE sample_date >= $start_date
```

or should I convert it somehow first

Comment: its alot easier to store your dates/times as unix timestamps and then just convert them to other formats for display.

Comment: I don't have that option at this time so what other solution is there.

Comment: @JohnB If I could -1 a comment I would.  Real date types are designed for storing dates, and MySQL has lots of internal functions to deal with them natively.

Comment: This question has been asked so many times. I'm searching for a suitable duplicate, but the crux of the answer is `strtotime()` in PHP. `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date))`

Comment: @michael ya but performance wise are Mysqls internal comparison functions faster to compare a date time than simply checking if one integer is greater than / less than/ or equal to another?  if so and you link it I'll -1 myself

Comment: @JohnB Inserts are faster with DATETIME, Selects are faster with INTs.  http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/

Comment: @Michael lol. plus 1 for pulling that up.  i was referring to ints.  Really the best solution to this is "it depends."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert the value as long as you've validated the format, but you should definitely sanitize the input to prevent XSS attacks and other nastiness. A calendar drop-down would be good here as well.

EDIT:
Whoa now... I see you've edited your question and the formats are different. That changes everything! Michael's comment is the correct answer, use strtotime() function to convert the date to a unix timestamp, then recreate the date in the proper format needed... like so... date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date))

Comment: js and a regex is prob the best way.

Comment: Actually someone else edited it.. It did have slashes originally!

Comment: A calendar drop-down would probably be best, otherwise you will still have to rely on your users entering the proper format. User's are foolish, don't rely on them to get anything right! :P

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace slashes with dashes.

```
$start_date = str_replace('/','-',$start_date);
$start_date = mysql_real_escape_string($start_date);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just append some zeros onto this:

```
$start_date = "2010-10-27";
$start_date .= " 00:00:00";
```

EDIT: Testing confirms that this is unnecessary. As long as the mysql column is DATETIME formatted, it understands "2010-10-27".

HOWEVER! Your example will throw an error, as Greater Than or Equal to should be written ">=", not "=>"